# I am getting the Index was outside the bounds of the array error

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am new to coding in unity and I wrote some code that was giving me the Index was outside the bounds of the array error, but I don't know what the problem is. If you could give me some insight on what I am doing wrong that would be great.This is the code that I wrote for a game that I am working on in unity:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 20.5f;

    public float HorizontalInput;

    public float xrange = 16;
    public GameObject[] projectileprefab;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            **//This is the broken line of code**
            int ProjectileIndex = Random.Range(0, projectileprefab.Length);
            Instantiate(projectileprefab[ProjectileIndex], transform.position, transform.rotation);





        }

        transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * speed * HorizontalInput);
        HorizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        if (transform.position.x < -xrange)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(-xrange, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
        }
        if (transform.position.x > xrange)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(xrange, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I just delete line  **//This is the broken line of code** and assgined gameobjects in editor and your code running well on my game without error :)

Answer (score 0):

problem is:

```
      int ProjectileIndex = Random.Range(0, projectileprefab.Length);
      Instantiate(projectileprefab[ProjectileIndex], transform.position, transform.rotation)
```

The length of projectileprefab is zero, so it instantiates the first object, but its empty. solution: in the inspector you can set the length of the projectileprefab array and assign game objects to it.